# use case diagram involving student paying, 4 relationships used

Tags: model, uml, use-case

I've tried learning this before and failed at it. My book talks about the different relationships between actors and says

1. "student" communicates with "enroll in course" - ok
2. "pay student fees is included by "enroll in course" and "arrange housing" "student health - not ok
3. "insurance" is an extension to "pay student fees" - not ok
4. "part time student" generalizes to "students" - ok

Wouldn't paying insurance be included in "pay student fees"? The text book says extends are for exceptions and I don't see how paying insurance is an exception?

When seeing a use case diagram how do you know where to start reading it from? Top left most symbol?

Are use-cases clear cut things in the sense that only one is right or can two different use cases correctly describe the same situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use case diagrams you start from the point where you need to. [In this diagram](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.agilemodeling.com/images/models/useCaseDiagram.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/useCaseDiagram.htm&h=481&w=538&sz=37&tbnid=C-zmxTpKVj-AXM%3a&tbnh=86&tbnw=96&prev=/search?q=use%2bcase%2bdiagram%2bexample&tbm=isch&tbo=u&zoom=1&q=use%20case%20diagram%20example&usg=__nx-mCrcXLHSyp-ETNMW9U_YzCwM=&sa=X&ei=mDlPUI-REorA9QS0ooCwBQ&ved=0CBwQ9QEwAA) If you are the studen you start with the studen and follow the paths that as they are questioned. I dont know what your aiming for here but I would write tests that say:

When_Student_Drops_Seminar_Registar_should_Distribute_Information_to_Students_and_Distribute_Transcripts

If you are a registar you would start from that person and etc